# Django image upload succeeds with url written to DB but no image shows upload target folder

Tags: python, django, windows, file-upload, django-uploads

I have form in Django

```
class BusinessForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField( required = True,
                             max_length=MAX_NAME_LENGTH,                                
                             widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'e.g Boston Market'}))        
    image = forms.ImageField()
```

which belongs to this model

```
class Business(models.Model):
    """ Describes Bussines data type """    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=BUS_NAME_LENGTH)         

    img = models.ImageField( upload_to = UPLOAD_TO )
```

where `UPLOAD_TO = 'business/images'`

and in the settings.py I have media root defined as follows

```
# Media Root - uploaded images
MEDIA_ROOT = '/uploads/'
```

in the database after I do an upload through the form I see the urls for example the following

[image: urls shown in mysql database for query]

However in the filesystem I do not see the file, I am running in test environment on localhost. I am using Windows OS.

[image: empty folder - explorer]

Why is that? Do I have to set some permissions to the folder? If so, how do I also make sure this will work in production when I deploy ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` aren't configured properly. Put the following code in your settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "uploads")
```

**Note**

If `BASE_DIR` is not defined in your settings file, put the following code on top of the file:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Comment: Is this expected to change on deployment or should just work? Also could you please point to documentation where we need to set that line in particular `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "uploads")`

Comment: never mind I see it here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/ and I missed "full path" and they have linux based example

Comment: @SaherAhwal *Is this expected to change on deployment...?* It depends on where you plan to save the uploaded files. If you want to save them in your backend server, then no. If you want to save them in a different (frontend) server, then yes.

Comment: Good answer. If you don't specify media url, upload image will not be stored in specified folder, even though to call server is success and path of the image is stored in db column.